# Can we shrink Android as an OS to use only 70-80% of the actual screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

What I want to achieve here is to shrink all of the Android's OS UI (everything inclusive) to use only 70-80% of the screen.

The reason is that I wish to have my area to put in whatever I want - apps icons which exist and are always visible (no matter if I am in a browser, or playing angry bird etc).. its like Windows's quick launch or Mac's dock which always stays there . I can also put some important text that I wish to see throughout my interaction with the device or anything else.

I just want to use 20-30% of the screen-size all by myself and run Android on the remaining portion of the screen.

[image]

Do you think it is possible? If so, can you please give me pointers?

Thanks much,

Rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for me:
1) create custom Android build. Change WindowManager code a little.
2) create own virtual keyboard which will serve keyboard and your stuff (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)